# Understanding proof that $C_c^{\infty}$ is dense in $C^{\infty}$ for the convergence in $C^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Prior notations: $\mathcal{E} = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\mathcal{D}=C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\subsetneq \mathcal{E}.$

Definition 'convergence in $\mathcal{E}$': $\psi_j\to \psi$ in $\mathcal{E}$ iff for each multi-index $\alpha$ we have that $D^{\alpha}\psi_j \to D^{\alpha}\psi$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (here: $D = \partial_{x_1}\dots \partial_{x_n}$).

> The subspace $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $\mathcal{E}$ for convergence in $\mathcal{E}$.

**Proof.** Let $\phi\in\mathcal{E}$. For each $j\in\mathbb{N}$, consider $\psi_j\in\mathcal{D}$ such that $\psi_j=1$ on $B(0,j)$. Then $\psi_j\phi \to \phi$ in $\mathcal{E}$.

**Questions**: why do such test functions $\psi_j$ exist?

As for the convergence, is this reasoning correct: Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $K\subseteq B(0,j)$ for sufficiently large $j$. Then $\psi_j\phi = \phi$ on $K$, so it's clear that $D^{\alpha}(\psi_j\phi)\to D^{\alpha}\phi$ uniformly (since we will have $\forall k\ge j: \forall x\in K: 0=|(\psi_k\phi)(x)-\phi(x)|<\varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon >0$ and similarly for all possible derivatives $D^{\alpha}$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence proof looks good to me.

**Existence of test functions with prescribed support**

First consider
$$f(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text{ if }t\leq 0\\
e^{-1/t} & \text{if }t>0\end{array}\right.$$
You can show that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ by induction. Now consider
$$g(t)=\dfrac{f(2-t)}{f(2-t)+f(t-1)}$$
It is $C^{\infty}$, $g(t)=1$ if $t\leq 1$ and $g(t)=0$ if $x\geq 2$. Finally
$$\psi(x)=g(\|x\|)$$
is a $C^{\infty}$ function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\psi(x)=1$ when $\|x\|\leq 1$ and $\psi(x)=0$ when $\|x\|>2$. It can be scaled with
$$\psi_j(x)=g\left(\dfrac{1}{j}\|x\|\right)$$
so that $\psi_j(x)=1$ on $B(0,j)$.

**Note**: This is the constructive approach. You can also construct such test functions by convolution methods.

Comment: Nice construction! Thank you very much. As for your note: is it possible to consider some kind of $C^{\infty}$-characteristic function? I.e. a function that will be 1 on $B(0,j)$ and will fall off continuously to 0 outside of it?